# In my ActionScript3 class, can I have a property with a getter and setter?

Tags: actionscript-3

In my ActionScript3 class, can I have a property with a getter and setter?

Comment: What do you mean?  You can have a class that has properties with getters and setters.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, well you can just use the basic getter/setter syntax for any property of your AS3 class.  For example

```
package {

    public class PropEG {

        private var _prop:String;

        public function get prop():String {
            return _prop;
        }

        public function set prop(value:String):void {
            _prop = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create getter and setter functions inside an AS3 class.

Example:

```
private var _foo:String = "";

public function get foo():String{
    return _foo;
}

public function set foo(value:String):void {
    _foo= value;
}
```

more information about getters and setters can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=basic_as_139_08.html)

Answer (score 0):

A getter is a function with a return value depending on what we return.
A setter has always one parameter, since we give a variable a new value through the parameter.

We first create an instance of the class containing the getter and setter, in our case it is "a". Then we call the setter, if we want to change the variable and using the dot syntax we call the setter function and with the = operator we fill the parameter. To retieve the value for a variable we use the getter in a similar way as shown in the example (a.myVar). Unlike a regular function call we omit the parentheses. Do not forget to add the return type, otherwise there will be an error.

package 
{

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class App extends Sprite 
{
       private var tsecField:TextField;
       private var tField:TextField;

       public function App() 
       {
               myTest();
       }

       private function myTest():void 
       {
               var a:Testvar = new Testvar();

               tField = new TextField();
               tField.autoSize = "left";
               tField.background = true;
               tField.border = true;
               a.mynewVar = "This is the new var.";
               tField.text = "Test is: "+a.myVar;
               addChild(tField);
       }
}
```

}

import flash.display.Sprite;

import flash.text.TextField;

class Testvar extends Sprite 
{
    public var test:String;

```
public function Testvar() 
{
}
public function set mynewVar(newTest:String):void 
{
       test = newTest;
}
public function get myVar():String 
{
       return test;
}
```

}